# Regex Exact Number of Characters

Tags: regex

How to limit the number of characters (alpha or numeric or anything)

Example I have (x can be any character)

```
name.xxx-XXX-XXXXXX-name
name.XXXXXXX-name
```

I want to exclude those of the first format and I thought I should do something like

```
name.{7}*-name
```

I only want those with `7` characters between `.` and `-`

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: @Newbie, you commented on an answer that it's "either xxx-XXX-XXXXXX or the other", what did you mean exactly? Also, is there a difference between x and X? My example below will match as you say... `name.` and `-name` with 7 of "alpha or numeric or anything" in between. If this is not what you want, please clarify.

Answer (score 4):

You don't want just any 7 characters. You want 7 non-dash characters

```
name\.[^-]{7}-name
```

Comment: Hi actually the format is fixed which makes it easier it's always either xxx-XXX-XXXXXX or the other

Answer (score 1):

You just need to remove the `*` as this conflicts with the `{7}` and is not valid regex. The `*` means "0 or more" while the `{7}` means "exactly 7".

Also, if you want the actual dot between the name and the 7 characters, you'd want to add the dot by escaping it:

```
name\..{7}-name
```

This will match `name.XXXXXXX-name` as you hoped. As well as `name.Xa%X3XX-name` for example. The `.` will match pretty much any character besides newlines unless you add a flag for it.

Comment: -1: {7} is not a valid construct in theory (regular languages) and OP didn't actually specify a language

Comment: Which regex engine doesn't support `{7}`?

Comment: Other than the obvious (`name.{7}` in many languages is interpreted as 7 arbitrary characters -- note the `.`), some languages like VimL use `\{7}`

Comment: The OP specifically said "alpha or numeric or anything" which is generally `.`, also assuming the OP is using notation such as `{7}`. Anyway, not sure what your issue is. You better go downvote the other answer and other answers on tons of other questions.

Comment: you originally wrote `name.{7}-name`, and the `.` doesn't match a literal dot.  You fixed that.  However, since language wasn't specified, you can't assume that {7} is the syntax for 7 characters.  For example, in viml the syntax is \{7}

Comment: I had the `.{7}` as the OP had that, but I saw he had a literal dot in front on the examples so I also added that alternative which I then figured was the only alternative he really wanted so I deleted the first. Anyway, are you serious about this viml stuff? Seriously if you really feel that way you have quite a mission of downvotes to make.